# Width 100% Doesn't Mix with Margin-Right

Tags: html, css, overflow, margins, multiple-columns

I've searched for several hours and tried out everything I found, but nothing helped, so here goes.  I'm trying to set up a website that has a left column and right column both of width 200 pixels, while having the middle column taking up the remaining space.  I noticed that margin-right is completely ignored.  I tested out overflow, but that didn't seem to work either.  Granted, I might have done the overflow bit wrong.  Anyways, here's my test site, relevant CSS, and the HTML.

The current background for the middle column just doesn't do well with scaling, so I'll probably swap it for something else.

Site: http://mnslayer27.webs.com/bgtest.html

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Mnslayer27</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mnslayer27.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
</head>
<body>

  <iframe src="Main_Links.html" id="ml" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1808"></iframe>

<div id="left">
  <div id="right">
    <div id="column2">
      <div class="transbox"></div>
      <div class="transtext">
        <h1>Text~</h1><br />
      </div>
       sdtfghujikjuhygtfrdsfghjklhkgjhfdsdfghkn
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="column3">
  <h3>Pictures</h3>
  <div id="pics">
    <img src="http://i195.photobucket.com/albums/z255/yukina17/letter%20r/rave%20master/Elie.jpg" border="0" width="100%" alt="Elie" title="Elie"></img><br /><br /><br />
    <img src="http://mnslayer27.webs.com/Sasuke%20Eternal%20Mangekyou.gif" border="0" width="100%" alt="Sasuke's Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan" title="Sasuke's Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan"></img>
    <center><img src="http://mnslayer27.webs.com/Torch.gif" border="0" width="50%" alt="Torch" title="Torch"></img></center><br /><br />
  </div>
</div>

CSS:
#left {
  //overflow:hidden;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

#right {
  margin-right:200px;
}

div.transbox  {
   width:100%;
  //width:auto;
  height:180px;
  margin:0px 0px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:none;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

#column2 {
        position: absolute;
        top: 120px;
        //left: 200px;
        overflow:hidden;
    color: #000000;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
        height: 1688px;
        //margin-left: 200px;
        //margin-right: 200px;
        border: none;
        background-image: url("http://i246.photobucket.com/albums/gg106/mnslayer27/Ren-Winamp2.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using absolute position and specify the left and right for the divs instead of using width.

```
#left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;  
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #d0c0c0;
}

#right
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;            
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #d0c0c0;
}

#centre
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color: #a0a0d0;

    border: solid 2px black;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

This also has the advantage that any added margin,border or padding do not extend the divs making the whole become wider than the 100% of the page.

Heres a simple [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUeUn/)

hope that helps

Comment: I didn't even know you could absolute position both left and right.  Thanks!  This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433230/fixed-left-and-right-columns-liquid-middle-unable-to-span-entire-page/12433311#12433311) that helped someone with just about the same exact issue. There's a JSFiddle included

Comment: Not quite sure why, but that didn't work for me.  Damp solved it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not positive based on your question exactly what you want the final product to look like but based on your three column approach and trying to get your margins to work properly try floating all three of your columns, like so

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Mnslayer27</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Mnslayer27.css" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii" />
        <style>


div.transbox  {
   width:100%;
  //width:auto;
  height:180px;
  margin:0px 0px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:none;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.column1
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 100px 0 100px;
}

#column2 {


    color: #000000;
    float:left;

        border: none;
        background-image: url("http://i246.photobucket.com/albums/gg106/mnslayer27/Ren-Winamp2.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-attachment: scroll;

}
#column3
{
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}


        </style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="column1">   
  <iframe src="Main_Links.html" id="ml" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="1808"></iframe>
</div>


    <div id="column2">
      <div class="transbox"></div>
      <div class="transtext">
        <h1>Text~</h1><br />
      </div>
       sdtfghujikjuhygtfrdsfghjklhkgjhfdsdfghkn
    </div>

<div id="column3">
  <h3>Pictures</h3>
  <div id="pics">
    <img src="http://i195.photobucket.com/albums/z255/yukina17/letter%20r/rave%20master/Elie.jpg" border="0" width="100%" alt="Elie" title="Elie"></img><br /><br /><br />
    <img src="http://mnslayer27.webs.com/Sasuke%20Eternal%20Mangekyou.gif" border="0"  alt="Sasuke's Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan" title="Sasuke's Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan"></img>
    <center><img src="http://mnslayer27.webs.com/Torch.gif" border="0"alt="Torch" title="Torch"></img></center><br /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason the middle column didn't display.

Comment: did you change your HTML markup, I added a new div for a column

Comment: Ah, I didn't.  I just tried and for some reason it messed with the layout.  Damp was able to fix it, so you don't have to keep helping, unless you want to.  I must have really butchered the code, so I'm open to anything that works for the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your `div` to be `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: block;`, it may solve the issue you're having. Be aware that this may have other consequences in your code though. I'd be way of using a solution that involves `position: absolute;` as well though, because this can get messy when you have other elements interacting with it/each other.

I'm sure there was a method involving `box-sizing: border-box;` but I can't seem to work it out right now.